# Subgraphs of the Permutohedron

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations, subgraph

I've been looking at connected induced subgraphs permutohedrons (viewed as graphs). I was wondering if there's any research into this subject. Also if you have good sources about the permutohedron I would appreciate it.

Comment: The $1$-skeleton of the permutohedron is just the Cayley graph of the symmetric group $S_n$ with respect to the generating set of adjacent transpositions. Possibly from this perspective you will be able to find more information about its graph-theoretic properties/structure.